# make multi dimensional array cloning optional

Tags: java, arrays, option-type, cloning

The method below works fine:

```
private static int[][] multiArrayClone(int[][] multiArray) {
    if (multiArray != null)
        return Arrays.stream(multiArray).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new);
    else
        return null;
}
```

But I am looking for the way of use `java.util.Optional<T>`, instead of "if null" conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can have:

```java
private static int[][] multiArrayClone(Optional<int[][]> multiArray) {

    return multiArray.isPresent() ? 
            Arrays.stream(multiArray.get()).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new) : null;

}
```

However, bear in mind, that you will need to be providing an `Optional<int[][]>`, and not just `int[][]`, as an argument.

Alternatively, you can instantiate `Optional<T>` locally, if you want to avoid it as a parameter:

```java
private static int[][] multiArrayClone(int[][] multiArray) {
    Optional<int[][]> mr = Optional.of(multiArray);
    
    return mr.map(ints -> Arrays.stream(ints).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new)).orElse(null);

}
```

As you [can see](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java), `Optional<T>` is a wrapper for null checks behind the scenes.

While it can be justified to use `Optional<T>` in streams, it's not a good idea to swap all the null-checks with optionals. Actually, they are sometimes even more verbose doing a bit more than just null-checks, and they *do not* improve performance in contrast to simple null-checks.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is there any performance benefit from such a solution? How to measure it?

Comment: @AndrzejWięcławski of course not. There’s no magic connected to `Optional`. These variants are just more complicated, without any benefit.

Comment: @AndrzejWięcławski I have included point about performance in the answer as well. Some call it *glorified* null-check.. and as I said, in some cases, it can be nice to use it, but my *personal opinion* about `Optional<T>`s isn't very exciting. I think it didn't bring anything super important or useful, in Java. But that's my personal opinion and some may not subscribe to it. In many cases, it can even bloat and complicate the code readability.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri In my question I was driven by the desire to make the code more efficient, but apparently I was wondering unnecessarily about something I don't know very well;) Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether using `Optional` *inside* your method has any advantages. Returning an `Optional` from the method is probably advantageous.

You can elegantly do both:

```
private static Optional<int[][]> multiArrayClone(int[][] multiArray) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(multiArray)
            .map(ma -> Arrays.stream(ma).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new));
}
```

Depending on your requirements you may also want to consider returning an empty array in the case where the argument is `null`. This could free the caller from taking `null` or an empty `Optional` into account.

```
private static int[][] multiArrayClone(int[][] multiArray) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(multiArray)
            .map(ma -> Arrays.stream(ma).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new))
            .orElse(new int[0][]);
}
```

Comment: It returns null only in 2nd dimension of instantiated ArrayList in case the method argument is null? After test: multiArrayClone(null) -> []. Interesting, but I did not plan to handle such a result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please? The second snippet in the case of `null` returns an outer array of length 0, that is, with no elements in it, also no `null` elements. But just discard the idea if it isn’t useful to you. I am letting it stand since it may be useful for others.